# Function doesn't hide div after setted time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need the //OUT function to hide my div after 3 seconds instead of 1 second. I guess the problem is that I should apply something to trigger the //OUT function after the div is shown but I don't know how to solve it. please help. I need the function //OUT to work independently, don't want to add anything to the //IN function because some divs appear after scroll and I want them to hide at setted time also.

```js
// OUT
$(function() {
    $("[class*=outtime]").each(function() {
        var retraso = parseInt($(this).attr("class").match(/outtime\d+/g)[0].replace("outtime",""));
        setInterval("$('.outtime" + retraso + "').fadeOut(0)", retraso * 1000);
    });
});

// IN
$(function() {
    $("[class*=intime]").each(function() {
        var retraso = parseInt($(this).attr("class").match(/intime\d+/g)[0].replace("intime",""));
        $(this).delay(retraso * 1000).fadeIn(0);
    });
});
```

```css
.cuadrado{ height:100px;width:100px; background:red;display:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cuadrado intime2 outtime3">
</div>
```

Comment: you can use .fadeTo(3000, 0).fadeTo(1000,1);

Comment: It doesn't wouldn't work as I need.

Comment: $(element).fadeTo(3000,0); 3 second duration to opacity 0 (fade out)

Comment: So you want the div to appear and reappear every 3 seconds?

Comment: @theblindprophet no, I want the div to appear at 2 seconds with the //IN function and disappear 3 seconds after with //OUT function; not reappear.

Comment: You would want this to happen with every div on the page? Once that specific div is shown then that specific div should disappear after 3 seconds?

Comment: Yeah, any element with "outtime*" class should disappear after a given * time @theblindprophet

Comment: Because what is happening now is both functions are called when the script is loaded so it's like: 0...1s...2s (appear)...3s (disappear). And that is why it disappears one second after appearing. I have answer for you, but involves calling OUT from inside IN which you seemed to not want to do.

Comment: No @theblindprophet this is why I think I should call the function //OUT when the div appears but I don't know how...

Comment: if you dont want this to repeat why do we have the setInterval in the //OUT

Comment: Because it's the only way I found to make the code work as I want but when I started to simplify new problems appeared.

Comment: only way I can see this happening is if in the //in, you apply `$(this).delay(retraso * 1000).fadeIn(0, function(){ //call fade out(fade in is complete) });`

Comment: I don't know why but it works here but not in Dreamweaver... I don't know if it means it solved or not...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
// OUT
function fadeOut(){
    $("[class*=outtime]").each(function() {
        var retraso = parseInt($(this).attr("class").match(/outtime\d+/g)[0].replace("outtime",""));
        $(this).fadeTo(retraso*1000,0);
    });
};

// IN
function fadeIn(){
    $("[class*=intime]").each(function() {
        var retraso = parseInt($(this).attr("class").match(/intime\d+/g)[0].replace("intime",""));
        $(this).fadeTo(retraso*1000,1, function(){
         fadeOut();
        });
    });
};
fadeIn();
```

```css
.cuadrado{ height:100px;width:100px; background:red;display:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cuadrado intime2 outtime3">
</div>
```

Comment: reuse what you had before with `$(this).delay(retraso * 1000).fadeIn(0, , function(){
         fadeOut();
        }));` , I assumed you might of wanted the transition of opacity

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".cuadrado").each(function() {
    var el = $(this);
    var outtime = parseInt(el.attr("class").match(/outtime\d+/g)[0].replace("outtime", "")) * 1000;
    var intime = parseInt(el.attr("class").match(/intime\d+/g)[0].replace("intime", "")) * 1000;
    el.fadeTo(intime, 1).fadeTo(outtime, 0);
    setInterval(function() {
      el.fadeTo(intime, 1).fadeTo(outtime, 0);
    }, outtime + intime);
  });
});
```

```css
.cuadrado {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: red;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cuadrado intime2 outtime3">
</div>
```

Comment: This is not what I need you can check it at the comments above. thanks for answering :)

Comment: to stop it repeat remove the setInterval

Comment: The problem is I want the //OUT function to work separately because it happens to be mixed with other functions showing divs on scroll or on click.